# Daisy-chain non-display port displays

Tags: macos, display, thunderbolt, displayport

I have a Mac Mini (Mid 2011) running OS X Lion with two monitors currently hooked up to it. One is a DVI monitor (it also supports VGA) and the other is VGA-only.

- The DVI monitor is currently hooked up using the HDMI port on the Mac Mini, with, of course, an HDMI to DVI adapter.
- The other monitor is currently hooked up using a DisplayPort to VGA adapter.

This all just works fine. But whenever I want to watch a video on my TV (for example), I have to put the TV into the HDMI port, thereby disconnecting my main monitor. I was wondering if it is possible to daisy chain this.

I want to just hook up an adapter or something like that, put my two monitors in there and then just hook up the TV, being able to use it whenever I want to.

Is it possible to do such a thing? I know it's possible by using two Thunderbolt monitors, daisy chaining them and then plug in the other display (a TV for example...) to the HDMI port. However, I don't want to buy two new display's...

Thanks in advance,
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to daisy chain displays through Mini DisplayPort.

However, there is a company called [DisplayLink](http://displaylink.com/) that makes software drivers for USB video adapters. They also have [links in their store](http://displaylink.com/shop/adapters) to Mac compatible, DisplayLink approved USB display adapters. One of my coworkers uses this to connect a MacBook Pro to two external displays and a TV in his office. It uses the extended desktop feature for each display. It's a pretty sweet setup and works flawlessly.

I see no reason why this wouldn't work for you. Good luck!

Comment: Also you might consider adding something like an Apple TV to your TV. It will do a good job of streaming video from your mac and also take some load of your mac mini's CPU. And should be less CPU overhead and resource use than a USB to HDMI video adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the tip MrDaniel, but it's just an example, I could also want to add another screen for instance :-)